# Iterate over dynamic object fields and get field data type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection

I have object in dynamic type, and index variable in Int data type. Is it possible to get type of field of dynamic object in given index?

Pseudocode:

```
dynamic dynamicObject = ...
var type = GetType(dynamicObject.Fields[index]); // Int, String or another.
```

For instance

```
dynamic dynamicObject = new
{
   Name = "Bla",     
   Age = 2,
   Surname = "Bla Bla"
};
int index = 2;
```

And I want to get System.String

Comment: invoke GetType() properly: `var type = dynamicObject.Fields[index].GetType();`

Comment: thanks for your answer but .Fields[index] made up by me. There is no such code :) I wanted just to explain what I want to do :)

Comment: you could have posted an example of specific dynamicObject, specific index / indices, and expected result / results

Comment: `dynamic dynamicObject = new
{
    Name = "Bla",
    Age = 2,
    Surname = "Bla Bla",
};
int index = 2;`
And I want to get System.String.

Comment: why index=2 should return String?

Comment: because if we can get the fields of dynamic object as array or list, [2] will return Surname field and the type of Surname is String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use reflection. it will work just as well if you use `object` type instead of `dynamic`, or allow type inference with `var`:

```
var dynamicObject = new
{
   Name = "Bla",     
   Age = 2,
   Surname = "Bla Bla"
};
int index = 2;
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] allProps = dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperties();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = allProps[index];
Type type = prop.PropertyType;
```

Comment: one more thing: avoid multiple GetProperties() calls - reflection is a costly operation. call it once and save result in additional variable.

Comment: Hi again. I'm really sorry but I need your help. Can you visit this [link](https://pastebin.com/t6Zz5FiT)? I defined the problem in there